# How to hide new close Button in WatchOS storyboard in xcode 15?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, watchos

Some time ago i made a WatchOS app with storyboard and everything was working fine, but after the upgrade to xcode 15, the same app has now suddenly a close button. i didnt add it myself, it was just there when i installed it on my watch again.
to present pages i use ...

```
presentController(withNames: <[String], contexts: <[Any])
```

that was enough to avoid such a close button. but since the upgrade there is obviously a new code needed. has anyone an idea or maybe experienced the same trouble i run into?
i am already working to convert my Storyboard version to a SwiftUI version, but till then i would love to let my old app run on my watch properly.

[image: my watch app]